Why is this happening when using try and except and how do I fix it?
I wrote the following program to Calculate Pay plus time and a half for anything over 40 hours.
x = input(‘Enter Hours:’)
y = input(‘Enter Rate:’)
xy = float(x)*float(y)
text = ‘Pay:’
xr = ((float(x)-40)
xrt = (float(xr))*float(y)*0.5
ot = float(xrt+xy)
if(float(x))<=40:
    print(text,day)
elif(float(x))>40:
    print(text,it)

I'm trying rewrite my program using try and except so that it handles non-numeric input gracefully by printing a message exiting the program. This is what I got so far on the try and except:
try:
    x = input(‘Enter Hours:’)
    y = input(‘Enter Rate:’)
    xy = float(x)*float(y)
    text = ‘Pay:’
    xr = ((float(x)-40)
    xrt = (float(xr))*float(y)*0.5
    ot = float(xrt+xy)
    if(float(x)) <= 40:
        print(text,xy)
    elif(float(x)) > 40:
        print(text,ot)
except:
    print(‘Error, please enter numeric input’)

If the user enters an invalid answer when it says Enter Hours: say they put "forty" it still prompts the next input Enter Rate: and only after that does it print Error, please enter numeric input. But what I want it to do is stop and print Error, please enter numeric input as soon as they enter "forty" or something invalid (something that is not a number) how would I go about this? I know there are more simple ways to write this code and I know you are not usually supposed to use floating point numbers for money, I'm not worried about that, I just want to know how to achieve the question above where as soon as you enter a string instead of number it prints my error message?

It you want to check the first input is a valid number before taking the second input, then don't immediately take the second input without checking the first one.

You have syntax errors in your code, and even if they are fixed the error message will never be printed because you call float(x) and float(y) even before the try.

thank you for your help! I was thinking something like that but I am brand new to this Python is my first language I am learning and I'm only on my 3rd week of the course Python for Everybody so I'm not quite sure exactly how to do that could you show me an example?

well im not sure if i wrote it wrong on here but i have ran the program and it works.... the only problem i am having is that it prints the error code after BOTH inputs even if the first input is a string... it still asks for the second input and then prints the error message but if they input a number and then a string it works fine..obviously so what Im asking is how do i make it where it stops after the first input if they input a string instead of a number?

Apart from the issues already highlighted, you are missing declarations for day and it. Your statement that "it works" is incorrect. Neither of the code fragments can possibly work

@MadisonMacCoon See where the error happens. Compare that to y = input(‘Enter Rate:’). Is the line that causes error before or after your second input line?

try:
x = input('Enter Hours:')
y = input('Enter Rate:')
xy = float(x)*float(y)
text = 'Pay:'
xr = ((float(x))-40)
xrt = (float(xr))*float(y)*0.5
ot = float(xrt+xy)
if (float(x)) <= 40:
print(text,xy)
elif (float(x)) > 40:
print(text,ot)
except:
print('Error, please enter numeric input')

@MadisonMacCoon Code in comments is unreadable. Update your question instead

okay now that i went and looked at my program i did put the try and except in the wrong place on this question im trying to figure out how to edit the question now to fix it

okay like i said i wrote it wrong on here i just updated it to what i had wrote on the actual program

You can help yourself by writing a utility function that will prompt for some input that needs to be convertible to float. In that way, if the function returns, the value is guaranteed to be a float type.
For example:
def get_float(prompt: str) -> float:
    while True:
        value = input(prompt)
        try:
            return float(value)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

Then, you can acquire the input values like this:
hours = get_float("Enter hours: ")
rate = get_float("Enter rate: ")

Consequently, the multiple calls to float() become redundant and your calculations are simplified to:
pay = hours * rate if hours <= 40 else rate * 40 + (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5

print(f"Pay = \u20B9{pay:.2f}")

